# Differential equation and Lie algebra

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups, lie-algebras

If I have this differential equation:
$$ \frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} = F(\vec{x}) $$
and when $F = A$ is a matrix we can have the solution:
$$ \vec{x}(t) = e^{At} \; \vec{x} $$
But what if $F = \mathfrak{g} $ is a Lie algebra, then can we have:
$$ \vec{x}(t) = e^{\mathfrak{g} t} \; \vec{x} \quad ?$$
and if that is true, then the Lie group $ G = e^\mathfrak{g} $ leads to this solution:
$$ \vec{x}(t) = G \; e^t \; \vec{x} $$
Is this correct?

Comment: It does not make any sense for F to be a Lie algebra.

Comment: How about:  F as the matrix representation of a Lie algebra?

Comment: The point is that I want to use the "exponential map" for Lie algebras, and there is a way to extend the notion to non-matrix Lie groups...  which might lead to something useful.

Comment: If you pick any sensible textbook about Lie groups you will find that there is a well established notion of exponential map for all Lie groups, matrix or not matrix ones.

Comment: It's an old question, but @YanKingYin didn't really get an explanation why it doesn't make sense for $F$ to be a Lie algebra. Probably Yan is confusion a Lie algebra with an element of a Lie algebra. A Lie algebra is a set with an operation. It makes more sense for $F$ to be an *element* of a Lie algebra. Then the exponential belongs to the corresponding Lie group, and the group can act on something, e.g. on a vector space.